# Strategy for tackling the $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn}{(1+n)^n}$

Tags: limits

What strategy should I use to calculate this limit? Can I avoid using Hopital?

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn}{(1+n)^n}$$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $|(-1)^n n/(1+n)^n|=n/(1+n)^n\le n/n^n=1/n^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\ge 2$ we have $(1+n)^n\ge (1+n)^2\ge n^2$ and already $\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^2}=\frac{(-1)^n}n\to 0$.

Comment: $\frac{-(-1)^n}{n^2}\leq \frac{(-1)^nn}{(1+n)^n}\leq \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ and then the "Squeeze rule right?

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is: write $\dfrac{(-1)^nn}{(1+n)^n}=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^{n-1}} \dfrac{n^n}{(1+n)^n}=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^{n-1}} \dfrac{1}{(1+\dfrac{1}{n})^n}$.

hence we have:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\dfrac{(-1)^nn}{(1+n)^n}\right]
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^{n-1}} \dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}\\\,\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^{n-1}} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n}\\
&=0 \cdot \dfrac{1}{e}=0\\
\end{align}
$$